# Copy/paste Lightbox script for third-party sites

Tags: javascript

I want to give my clients a few bits of copy/paste code so that a Lightbox shows on their site with an iframe showing a URL that I specify. This would be something similar to a support widget that comes up when you click on a button (ZenDesk, UserVoice, etc.).

I've been trying to write this on my own, but after attempting to include jQuery on page load plus the Lightbox CSS file, it's proven to be a little bit of a mess.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I can create an optimal bit of JS that can accomplish this? Perhaps a framework already exists so that I don't need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I found something reliable. Decided to use http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/